# shape editor, troubles with my buffer

Tags: c#

I am currently making a shape editor, users will be able to draw shapes like "circle" or "stars" as you can see on the picture below. In order to cross my canvas as fast as possible, I composed my canvas of several areas. Like this, we will only check which shapes of the intersected areas with my view (green rectangle) are in my view, instead of checking which shapes of the entire canvas are in my view.

[IMAGE TO VISUALIZE AREAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nA98.png)

If an area does have an interaction with the user, the area will be composed of a set of small bitmaps. (each bitmap represents a shape) So we will paint a set of small bitmaps.

In the other case, If an area doesn't have any interaction with the user. we will paint a unique big bitmap which wraps the entire area.

But here is my issue :

In the second case, so visible areas are painted thanks to their own and unique bitmap, and when I am zooming too much I receive on the face this error message : **"the parameter is not valid"**. This error message appears when I am creating a new buffer.

HERE I make my buffer :

```
internal Bitmap UpdateBuffer(Single xZoom, Single yZoom){
var relativeSize = new SizeF(Frame.Width*xZoom, Frame.Height*yZoom);
Buffer = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(relativeSize.Width), Convert.ToInt32(relativeSize.Height));
...
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Buffer)){
    foreach (var shape in shapes)
        graphics.FillRegion(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Region(shape));
    graphics.Dispose();
}
return Buffer;
}
```

HERE I paint :

```
protected sealed override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
foreach (var dynamicArea in dynamicAreas){
   foreach (var item in dynamicArea.Items)
       item.OnPaint(e); // First case
}
foreach (var area in staticAreas){
    area.OnPaint(e); // Second case
}
```

So I would like to know if I am doing things very badly (in this case would you please indicate me the good way to do it) or if it exists another way more efficient for making buffer for my areas.

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT :** I think I have this message because I allocate too much memory, do I have to do a zoom limitation?????

Comment: you should not dispose a thing you create in a using clause

Comment: Use the debug - exceptions dialog to break when a CLR exception is thrown, run it in debug and see which line throws the exception. It will probably be because you are passing a negative value to the Bitmap constructor or similar.

Comment: Ok thank you I remove it

Comment: Actually, I have an exception when my bitmap's size is more or less 4000x4000. I cannot have bigger